# Does Expresso Store Have a USPS International shipping plugin?

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

I am tring to add an international shipping method. But the Store USPS plugin uses 
'API' => 'RateV4' Which is for domestic shipping. 'API' => 'RateV2' is for International Shipping. Do I need to just change some values in the default USPS Shipping plugin to make this work?

Comment: When I checkout in the USA the shipping rates calculate. But when checking out for shipping to a different country the shipping defaults to $0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USPS has separated the International API from Domestic API ([Docs](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/rate-calculators-v1-7a.htm)) so you would need a new shipping plugin to calculate international rates. In the meantime you can use UPS, FedEx or the Default Shipping Plugin for international orders.